# Different alignment of text in dzen2

Tags: statusbar

If I have two strings "foo" and "bar" and I want them displayed in dzen2 like this:

```
[foo         bar]
```

is it possible to do this without using the -ta option at all, just positioning commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it does require knowledge of the width of 1 char in that font, and the length of text you want to align.
To float something left, you would need to use:

```
^pa(_LEFT)^p(-[n*k])sometext
```

Where n is the number of chars in "sometext" and k is the pixel width of one char.

Dzen [does come](https://github.com/robm/dzen/blob/master/gadgets/README.textwidth) with a program, `textwidth` for calculating the size of non-monospace fonts, in chich case [n*k] would be replaced by that value.

I would recommend using a native version of the code if you can for efficiency, I have a version for golang [here](https://github.com/TShadwell/dzen-gadgets-go/blob/master/gadgets/go/textwidth.go), but if this is not possible you can just run the `textwidth` command.

SVN revision 255 of dzen apparently contains a ^ba(width, align) command, see the wiki.

Comment: So, this only applies for scenarios when a monospace font is being used?

Comment: Or when you can calculate the width of the non-monospace font.

Comment: I should have mentioned that dzen does come with [a program](https://github.com/robm/dzen/blob/master/gadgets/README.textwidth) for calculating the width of non-monospace fonts, I'll add it to the answer.